# What is the difference in memory usage and reference counting in "has-a" and "is-a" relationship in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, perl-data-structures

I read the "Programming Perl" book which is rather complicated in some places. And one of those places is the section "Instance Destructors" in the 12th chapter "Objects". This section says:

1. Objects in Perl are destroyed when there is no more references to them.
2. There is an opportunity to capture control just before object is going to be recycled by defining `DESTROY` method in its class.
3. Although destructors are rarely needed in Perl, some objects may have, for instance, filehandles or database connections, which are outside of the memory system. So it is necessary to attend them specially.
4. Perl does not do hierarchical destruction.

Then there is a paragraph which I failed to understand:

> **This only applies to inherited classes;** an object that is simply contained within
>   the current object—as, for example, one value in a larger hash—will be freed
>   and destroyed automatically. This is one reason why containership via mere ag-
>   gregation (sometimes called a “has-a” relationship) is often cleaner and clearer
>   than inheritance (an “is-a” relationship).

I can't understand what it means. Does it mean that *an object that* **IS NOT** *simply contained within the current object,* **WILL NOT** *be freed and destroyed automatically*?

I do know that a `DESTROY` that is called on the garbage collection is the nearest one and only one. No other overridden `DESTROY` methods are called when there is no refs to an instance. But, as I understand, the same behavior is expected when a ref to an instance is placed inside another object.

Would someone be so pleasant to construe and to **provide a code-example** ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Actually what I was looking for, was the explanation of the **This only applies to inherited classes;** words which turned out to be that:

*If you have an instance of a class and it has a `DESTROY` method than that method will override `DESTROY` methods of a parent class(es), but that does not apply to an object, that is in a `has-a` relationship with the object in question. Its `DESTROY` won't be overridden*

Sorry for not clear question, it would better fit to the English Language and Usage. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: The title of your question asks about the difference between has-a and is-a relationships, but the body of the question talks about memory usage and reference counting. It is not likely you need to worry about that at this point. I have only responded to the has-a vs. is-a question in my answer, and did not discuss memory management, scoping, reference counting, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rule 1: Objects in Perl are destroyed when there is no more references to them.

```
{
  my $object = Class->new()
}
# there are no more references to $object
# (it is out of scope and can't be accessed by any means)
# Perl is free to garbage-collect it.
```

#### Rule 2: There is an opportunity to capture control just before object is going to be recycled by defining DESTROY method in its class.

```
package Class;
sub new     { return bless({}, shift) }
sub DESTROY { print STDERR "The object is destroyed" }

####

{
  my $object = Class->new();
}
# before the object is garbage-collected, cleanup-operations should be manually performed
# like closing down connections, solving circular references
# any time, the object might print it's message.
```

#### Rule 4: Perl does not do hierarchical destruction.

```
package AnotherClass;
use Class;
use parent 'Class';
sub DESTROY { print STDERR "subclass reporting dead" }
```

Now if `AnotherClass` will be instantiated, only the `DESTROY` method of `AnotherClass`  will be called, **not** the `DESTROY` method of `Class`. This is meant with the absence of a hierarchical destruction. This is obvious, as the `DESTROY` method overwrites the previous entry. The original `DESTROY` can be called manually

Using a parent class and a child class is a IS-A relationship: `AnotherClass` is a `Class`.

If we have YetAnotherClass:

```
package YetAnotherClass;
use Class;
sub new {return bless({member => Class->new()}, shift) }

{
   my $object = YetAnotherClass->new();
}
# $object goes out of scope (zero reference count) and will be destroyed.
# Therefore, the reference count of the "member" drops to zero
# The member will therefore be destroyed and print it's message.
```

This is a case of aggregation (`Class` is a data member of `YetAnotherClass`), and a HAS-A relationship.

Comment: @DavidO The rules are copy-pasted from OPs question. So yes, while there is a rule 3, I didn't feel like writing something about it.

Comment: @amon, Thanks, I understood this. But what is the difference? Does it mean that when object is inside another object, there is no need to manually perform some cleanup actions? For now I see no difference in garbage collection or something else between case when a ref to an `$obj` is saved in lexical variable and when it is saved as a part of another object.

Comment: @caligula *Usually* you don't have to think about destroying or cleaning up objects at all. If a value is a lexical var itself or just a part of a lexical variable makes no difference. But when you define an object with a `DESTROY` method, you should be aware that no `DESTROY` calls are *automatically* made to parent classes. In most cases, this is highly irrelevant.

Comment: @amon, would you mind if I ask, does the snippet from the book mean that an object that `IS NOT` simply contained within the current object, `WILL NOT` be freed and destroyed automatically? I edited the question and added to it this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. In a has-a relationship, the object often *has a* reference to the other object. Thus given the class `Van`, an instance of a `Van` has *wheels*. When that instance is destroyed, perl (the program) will call the destructor for `Wheel` objects separately, because they are two distinct objects.
2. In an is-a relationship, the reference for `Van` *IS* the same reference for the `Vehicle` object in question. Thus it does not, as some languages do, step through the hierarchy calling `DESTROY` on all the inherited *classes*, it simply calls `DESTROY` once for each blessed reference.

**NOTE:** #1 is not always the case. For example [inside-out objects](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Object%3a%3aInsideOut) do not *contain* references to subclasses, they are blessed scalar references whose addresses are used as a key into a lexical hash in the package. The lexical scope of the persistent package holds the reference, not the object. But this just serves to make it no direct correlation between class clean-ups and is-a/has-a relationships.

It is still clear that a *separate* destruction would need to be made, even despite that perl does not automatically reap these has-a relationships.

So I think the key to understanding this is that in has-a relationships, there is a *separate* reference which needs to be destroyed. Perl either does it automatically as a reference count is decremented, or you have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A has-a relationship is one in which an object simply stores another type of object. Just like an object can store a number or string, it can also store another object. It's really no more complicated than that.

```
package MyClass;
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $obj = bless {}, $class;
  $obj->{some_thing_else} = SomeOtherClass->new;
}
```

An is-a relationship is another name for inheritance.

```
package SomeSubClass;
use parent 'SomeParentClass'; 
# older ways to do this are 'use base' and pushing on @ISA.
```

There's nothing particular about those concepts as it pertains to Perl, but I have shown Perl examples above.

Your first example is just a standard Perl class. Your second example is a has-a relationship. Neither of your code snippts an example of inheritance (is-a).

[By the way, when calling `bless` in your method `new`, you should get the class name from the first parameter of new (as I have shown above), otherwise, people will not be able to inherit from your class without overriding `new`. If I call `SomeSubClass->new`, and SomeSubClass has inherited new from SomeParentClass, and SomeParentClass does what you just did, then I will get an object of the class SomeParentClass instead of SomeSubClass. (Of course, maybe you don't want your class to be inheritable, or you want new to be overridden, for whatever reason.)]

Perl's object system is very bare bones, you can make anything you want of it. But the community is moving toward something called Moose, a CPAN module which offers a more sophisticated object system built on top.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is a a relationship of 'is-a' and any attribute the class / package have (moose with '`has`') or hash keys of the blessed object (assuming the object is blessed into an hashref for instance) is a `has-a`